# Finding eigenvalue of a matrix expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cayley-hamilton

Consider the following matrix
$A=\left[\begin{array}{lll}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 0 \\ -3 & 1 & -2\end{array}\right]$

How can I find the eigenvalues of $3 \mathrm{~A}^{3}+5 \mathrm{~A}^{2}-6 \mathrm{~A}+2 \mathrm{I}$?

I know the matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $1,3,-2$ and also that I can use cayley Hamilton theorem and reduce the matrix expression, but that doesn't reduce it enough so that I can avoid multiplication of matricies.

Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: It is clear that $A$ has eigenvalues $1,3,-2$ as it is triangular.  Suppose that $v$ were an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ for the matrix $A$... can you reason that $v$ is also an eigenvector for $A^2$ with eigenvector $\lambda^2$?  Note, $A^2v = A(Av)$ and use what you know about eigenvectors.  Can you generalize and show that any matrix polynomial $f(A)$ will also have $v$ as an eigenvector with $f(\lambda)$ as the eigenvalue where we plug in the scalar $\lambda$ in place of $A$'s and $1$ in place of $I$'s?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If $Av = \lambda v$, then what can we say about $(3A^3 +5A^2 - 6A + 2I)v$?

Answer (score 1):

If  $a$   is a eigen value of the matrix $A$  then  $a^2$ is the eigen value for $A^2$...similar arguments for $A^m$, where m is a positive  integer.

Similarly, $k*a$ is the eigen value for $kA$.

Now  use the previously mentioned  rules (observations) to calculate the eigen value of any expression  with out calculating the  powers of the matrix.

Comment: Knowing $\LaTeX$ is an "overkill". You just need to write your formulae between dollar signs as `$A^2$` for $A^2$.

Comment: Please give me more information how to write the question perfectly.

Comment: @maa I've edited your question to format the mathematical expressions correctly. If you click "edit", you can see the changes that I made: all I did was put in `$....$` ("dollar signs") around any mathematical expressions.

Comment: You are my best friend.Take greeting  from me